# How do I use RegEx to extract information

Tags: regex

Can regex be used to extract all the information before the tweets?

Example input:

```
Fri Mar 15 23:58:48 CET 2013 (DMHardy_) "I went to buy some fruit
today but bought 3 Easter eggs instead" @Ribby27

Fri Mar 15 23:58:48 CET 2013 (fujimiiru) ＜画像＞
OKストア川越店購入「信州のチカラ　信州なめこ　JA全農長野」 検体重量892g。65000秒測定。
セシウム１３７、0.85±0.44Bq/Kg検出（参考値です。誤検出？） ゲルマで測定してみたいです。 

Fri Mar 15 23:58:49 CET 2013 (BiancaValverdde) RT @luscaspfvr: no
instagram parece a rihanna, na rua parece a alcione
```

Example output:

```
Fri Mar 15 23:58:48 CET 2013 (DMHardy_)
Fri Mar 15 23:58:48 CET 2013 (fujimiiru)
Fri Mar 15 23:58:49 CET 2013 (BiancaValverdde)
```

Comment: I am using java hard coding, too crude and i am looking for a better method

Comment: I have removed all the /n's with java then used "^(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+\\:\\d+\\:\\d+)\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\(\\w+\\))\\s(.+)" to split the rows in talend

Comment: but you have not tried regex yourself? this looks like you only need to match everything till first `)`

Comment: I am unfamiliar with regex haha

Answer (score 1):

try this. (sorry i am not sure it will work with java)

```
/^.+?\)/gm
```

see https://regex101.com/r/iPtCV3/1

`^` from line start

`.+?` everything till first

`\)`

I guess `m`ultiline flag must be set

Comment: Fri Mar 15 23:58:48 CET 2013 (DMHardy_) "I went to buy some fruit today but bought 3 Easter eggs instead" 

Fri Mar 15 23:58:48 CET 2013 (fujimiiru) ＜画像＞))
HI THERE HAHAHA(PSPS)

Fri Mar 15 23:58:49 CET 2013 (BiancaValverdde) RT @luscaspfvr: no instagram parece a rihanna, na rua parece a alcione

Comment: What happens when people type brackets in the tweet haha

Comment: doesnt matter because this matches only from line start till FIRST `)`, assuming all info is in one line.